# Replacing "\" value from String in iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift4

I have String shown below and I want to replace "\" this with "" but Xcode doesn't allow me to do so. It gives Error like "Unterminated string literal"

```
let jsonStr = "[{\"isSelected\":true,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":true,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"English\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Malay\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Chinese\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Tamil\"}]"
```

Code for replacing "\" to "" is:

```
let newString = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: what is final o/p you want? remove "\" or `Json` object?

Comment: I suppose you converted json to string. What do you want to do with that string ? Wouldnt it make sense to use JSONSerialization or JSONDecoder to decode the json and actually use it ?

Comment: Yes I want to convert it into JSON

Comment: JSON o/p @PratikPrajapati

Comment: `let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8); let jsonArray = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []); print("jsonArray:\n \(jsonArray)")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let jsonStr = "[{\"isSelected\":true,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":true,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"English\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Malay\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Chinese\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Tamil\"}]"
```

These `\` are to say: Do not interpret the next `"`, they escape it. If you don't, since they are used to delimit the start/end of the String, it's an escape sequence: `\"`.

One of the most known used for it is the `\n`, if you don't use the `\`, it will read `n` (the letter), not a new line.
Well, for the double quotes, it's the same: Do not interpret as a "code" value to delimit the start/end of the String.

You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

If you do `print("jsonStr:\n \(jsonStr)")`, you'll have in console:

```
$>jsonStr:
[{"isSelected":true,"languageProficiencies":[{"isSelected":true,"name":"Advance"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Proficient"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Basic"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Below Basic"}],"name":"English"},{"isSelected":false,"languageProficiencies":[{"isSelected":false,"name":"Advance"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Proficient"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Basic"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Below Basic"}],"name":"Malay"},{"isSelected":false,"languageProficiencies":[{"isSelected":false,"name":"Advance"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Proficient"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Basic"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Below Basic"}],"name":"Chinese"},{"isSelected":false,"languageProficiencies":[{"isSelected":false,"name":"Advance"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Proficient"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Basic"},{"isSelected":false,"name":"Below Basic"}],"name":"Tamil"}]
```

No `\` seen.

For the rest, with bad unwrapping, but more for the logic.

```
let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)
let jsonArray = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: [])
print("jsonArray:\n \(jsonArray)")
```

Comment: Perfect!! Works for Me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it into JSON.

```
let string = "[{\"isSelected\":true,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":true,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"English\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Malay\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Chinese\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Tamil\"}]"
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String, Any>]
    {
          print(jsonArray)
    } else {
        print("json can not be formed !!")
    }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

If you want to replace "/" then...

```
print(jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: ""))
```

Comment: I want to replace "\" this one not "/"

Answer (score 1):

i have same issue once try this

```
extension Data
{
func dataToJSON() -> Any? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: [])
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil
}
}


extension String
{        
    func decodeUrl() -> String
    {
        return self.removingPercentEncoding!
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
let yourJsonString = "".decodeUrl()
        if let data = yourJsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
            if let json = data.dataToJSON() {
                print(json)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the "\\" example like below.

```
let jsonStr = "[{\"isSelected\":true,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":true,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"English\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Malay\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Chinese\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Tamil\"}]"
let convertedStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
print(convertedStr)
```